# Check if a value of an array of dictionaries matches a list of array elements

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, predicate

I have an array (items) and an array of dictionaries (data) in Swift:

```
let items = [2, 6, 4]

var data = [
    ["id": "1", "title": "Leslie", "color": "brown"],
    ["id": "8", "title": "Mary", "color": "red"],
    ["id": "6", "title": "Joe", "color": "blue"],
    ["id": "2", "title": "Paul", "color": "gray"],
    ["id": "5", "title": "Stephanie", "color": "pink"],
    ["id": "9", "title": "Steve", "color": "purple"],
    ["id": "3", "title": "Doug", "color": "violet"],
    ["id": "4", "title": "Ken", "color": "white"],
    ["id": "7", "title": "Annie", "color": "black"]
]
```

I'd like to create an array that contains those arrays of dictionaries whose "id" equals to the numbers provided in the 'items' array. Aka I'd like to end up with having an array of:

```
var result = [
    ["id": "6", "title": "Joe", "color": "blue"],
    ["id": "2", "title": "Paul", "color": "gray"],
    ["id": "4", "title": "Ken", "color": "white"]
]
```

I was trying to use predicates, but after a severe headache and a cardiac arrest I didn't get nowhere with them. They seem insanely complex for this task. I'm now at a point where I just want to do this in a simple for-in loop.

Is there a clever way to do this using predicates or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `filter` and `contains` like this:

```
let result = data.filter { dict in
    if let idString = dict["id"], id = Int(idString) {
        return items.contains(id)
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work:

```
let items = [2, 6, 4]
var data = [
    ["id": "1", "title": "Leslie", "color": "brown"],
    ["id": "8", "title": "Mary", "color": "red"],
    ["id": "6", "title": "Joe", "color": "blue"],
    ["id": "2", "title": "Paul", "color": "gray"],
    ["id": "5", "title": "Stephanie", "color": "pink"],
    ["id": "9", "title": "Steve", "color": "purple"],
    ["id": "3", "title": "Doug", "color": "violet"],
    ["id": "4", "title": "Ken", "color": "white"],
    ["id": "7", "title": "Annie", "color": "black"]
]

var result = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

for index in 0..<data.count {
    let myData = data[index]
    let dataID = data[index]["id"]
    for i in 0..<items.count {
        if dataID == "\(items[i])" {
            result.append(myData)
        }
    }
}

for i in 0..<result.count {
    print(result[i])
}
```

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the reply! I think Eric D's solution comes closest to what I was after.

I was finally be able to find the solution with  good description on raywenderlich.com: https://www.raywenderlich.com/82599/swift-functional-programming-tutorial

Using that method (again, very close to what Eric D has suggested), first I can break it down as:

```
func findItems(value: [String: String]) -> Bool {
    return items.contains(Int(value["id"]!)!)
}
var result = data.filter(findItems)
```

I can further reduce that to:

```
var result = data.filter {
    (value) in items.contains(Int(value["id"]!)!)
}
```

Which, again, can be reduced to a single line, as in:

```
var result = data.filter { items.contains(Int($0["id"]!)!) }
```

Thanks again to everyone!

Comment: Only issue is that your solution(s) are *not safe*. There's force unwrapping and it can cause issues later. That's why I'm using `if let` in my answer. For example, your last solution is the exact equivalent of mine, minus the safety. :/